# Appending '-e' to a string in a bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that iterates over the arguments and builds a string like the following:

Usage:

```
./myScript a b c d
```

Expected output:

```
-e "a" -e "b" -e "c" -e "d"
```

The script looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

pattern=""

for arg in "$@" do
    pattern=$pattern" -e \"$arg\""
done

echo $pattern
```

The actual output misses the first `-e`, i.e., the output is:

```
"a" -e "b" -e "c" -e "d"
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to append `-e`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong. It is just that `echo` takes `-e` as an argument *.

```
$ pattern='-e asdf -e ghjk'
$ echo $pattern
asdf -e ghjk
```

If you quote the variable it works as expected.

```
$ echo "$pattern"
-e asdf -e ghjk
```

---

* `man echo`

> -e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes

Comment: This is one reason `printf` is preferred over `echo`.